# Cavendish experiment and electromagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, newtonian-gravity, experimental-physics, physical-constants

Flat Earther's deny the Cavendish experiment at all costs, and it's useless to debate with them, but I learn a lot by watching the nonsense they talk about and studying it. They say that the masses attract each other in the experiment due to electromagnetism, so my question is: what would be the consequences on the gravitational constant if the masses were attracting each other due to electromagnetism? How can we guarantee that there is no electromagnetism involved there?

Comment: "...it's useless to debate with them..." But, it sounds like maybe you _want_ to argue with them. Just keep in mind what George Bernard Shaw said about wrestling with pigs. https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/george_bernard_shaw_137450

Comment: honestly, after I realized that they don't want the truth, they just want to believe in something impossible, I stopped debating. But I'm still curious about the kind of things they come up with

Answer (score 3):

In $1600$ Gilbert proposed that what we now call the force of gravitational attraction was due to magnetism but over the years scientist eg Hooke in 1666, provided evidence that this was not so.

Cavendish was a brilliant experimenter and in his papers he included evidence that magnetism did not affect his results.  He also was well versed in the Earth's magnetic field around his property in London.

(By luck?) the alignment of the building in Cavendish's back garden which housed the apparatus meant that his torsion bar was "nearly parallel to East-West" thus reducing any effect that the Earth's magnetism might have.

[image]

Also Cavendish noted *In this trial, the rods by which the leaden weights were suspended were of iron; for, as I had taken care that there should be nothing magnetical in the arm, it seemed of no signification whether the rods were magnetical or not; but, for greater security, I took off the leaden weights, and tried what effect the rods would have by themselves.* and found no effect due due to magnetism.
*As a further proof of this, I took off the leaden weights, and in their room placed two 10-inch magnets; the apparatus for turning them round being left as it was, and the magnets being placed horizontal, and pointing to the balls, and with their north poles turned to the north ; but I could not find that any alteration was produced in the place of the arm, by turning them half round; which not only confirms the deduction drawn from the former experiment, but also seems to shew, that in the experiments with the iron rods, the effect produced could not be owing to magnetism.*

In 1838 Reich used $30\,\rm kg$ iron masses *which proves that no disturbance could have arisen from magnetic action*.

Answer (score 1):

If those masses were attracted to each other by electromagnetism instead of gravity, it means that lead (as used in the Cavendish experiment) is ferromagnetic, which it assuredly is not.

Another way to look at this is that if the cavendish result was due to electromagnetism, then the coupling constant for electromagnetism would have to be the same as that for gravity, which we know it isn't. Here's how much they differ by:  take two protons, position them one centimeter apart, and measure the strength of their gravitational attraction. Now move then 1.8 light-years apart and you will measure that at that distance, the strength of their electrostatic repulsion is equal to the strength of their gravitational attraction when 1 centimeter apart.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to estimate the amount of charge required to ruin the measurement:

$$ F_G = G \frac{m^2}{R^2} = \frac 1 {4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{q^2}{R^2} = F_E$$

which are equal if:

$$ q^2 = 4\pi\epsilon_0 G m^2 $$

For a reasonable test set up: two standard lab lead bricks (25 lbs each), you get:

$$ q = \sqrt{4\pi\epsilon_0 G} m = 6{\,\rm billion\ electrons}$$

for a total mass of 5 zg.

That's not much, and you can see why someone might think its possible.

Nevertheless, for a lead ball, that's a voltage of:

$$V = \frac 1 {4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac q R \approx 300\,{\rm V} $$

Very easy to measure and disregard.

also: try it with different metals or hollow/solid things (since charge is on the surface...e.g copper vs copper plated tungsten), and show it doesn't depend on those electrical factors.